# Output of interactive python to shell variable

Tags: python

There is an interactive python script something like

```
def myfunc():
    print("enter value between 1 to 10")
    i=int(input())
    if(i<1 or i>10):
        print("again")
        myfunc()
    else:
        print(i)
```

I want to store the final output which is `print(i)` in a shell variable. Something like

```
python myFile.py | read a
```

Above query get stuck everytime i run the command. Is it possible to do that?
Even though `( read b | python myFile.py ) | read a`  defeats the purpose of interactive python function but this doesn't work as well. It works if `myfunc()` is non-interactive(not expecting user input). The function in reality takes some input, manipulates it, and then output the result in required format. I know it would be much easier to use either python or shell, but since i already wrote the python function, was wondering if it is possible to link both. If yes, is it also possible to add only final value to shell variable rather than all the `print()`

Same issue happens(terminal gets stuck) when i do

```
python myFile.py > someFilename
```

However file `someFilename` was created even though terminal was unresponsive. It seems shell is starting both the processes at the same time which makes sense. I am guessing if somehow `python myfile.py` executes independently before opening the pipe it could be possible, but i may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on Linux or other Unix variants, would you please try:

```
import os
def myfunc():
    tty = os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_WRONLY)
    os.write(tty, "enter value between 1 to 10\n")
    i=int(input())
    if(i<1 or i>10):
        os.write(tty, "again\n")
        myfunc()
    else:
        print(i)
```

BTW if your shell is `bash`, it will be better to say:

```
read a < <(python myFile.py)
```

Otherwise `read a` is invoked in the subshell and the variable `a`
cannot be referred in the following codes.

Comment: this works great. thanks. one follow-up doubt though. when i just run this function as `python myfile.py` it throws error until i change string part in `os.write` to bytes. i converted it to bytes then when i tried to invoke from shell it threw error saying string expected. why so?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. What error message is given before you change the string to bytes? In my environment, Both `os.write(tty, "enter value between 1 to 10\n")` and `os.write(tty, bytes("enter value between 1 to 10\n"))` works.

Comment: following was the error: `os.write(tty, "enter value between 1 to 10\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. bytes doesn't work either `bytes("enter value between 1 to 10\n")` threw error `TypeError: string argument without an encoding` so had to add 'utf-8' parameter in the bytes function

Comment: i am actually trying in mac not linux, could that be the reason?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. It will not be macOS related but locale dependent. So you have added 'utf-8' parameter and now it works?